# how to group data in bins of 1 degree latitude?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, binning

I have some geographical data (global) as arrays:

- latitude: lats = ([34.5,34.2,67.8,-24,...])
- wind speed: u = ([2.2,2.5,6,-3,-0.5,...])

I would like to have a statement how the wind speed depends on latitude. Therefore I would like to bin the data in latitude bins of 1 degree.

*latbins = np.linspace(lats.min(),lat.(max),180)*

How can I calculate which wind speeds are falling in which bin. I read about pandas.groupby. Is that an option?

Comment: have a look at `pd.cut`.

Answer (score 0):

The numpy function [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) does this task.

Here one example that categorises each value in a bin:

```
import numpy as np
import math

# Generate random lats
lats = np.arange(0,10) - 0.5
print("{:20s}: {}".format("Lats", lats))
# Lats                : [-0.5  0.5  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5]

# Generate bins spaced by 1 from the minus to max values of lats
bins = np.arange(math.floor(lats.min()), math.ceil(lats.max()) +1, 1)
print("{:20s}: {}".format("Bins", bins))
# Bins                : [-1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]

lats_bins = np.digitize(lats, bins)
print("{:20s}: {}".format("Lats in bins", lats_bins))
# Lats in bins        : [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
```

As suggested by @High Performance Mark in the comments, since you want to split in bins with **1** degree, you can use the [`floor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html) to extract the floor of each `lats` (note: this method introduces negative index bins if there are negative values):

```
lats_bins_floor = np.floor(lats)
# lats_bins_floor = lats_bins_floor + abs(min(lats_bins_floor))
print("{:20s}: {}".format("Lats in bins (floor)", lats_bins_floor))
# Lats in bins (floor): [-1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.]
```